# ''automatic'' header for one-section chapter

Tags: header-footer, conditionals, fancyhdr

I am writing my master final work in `LaTeX`using `memoir class`. For the `header/footer` I am using `fancyhdr` with the code

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\small\textbf{\arabic{page}}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\small{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\small{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\space#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
```

It works fine when the text has, at least, one section. However, in chapters as introduction or conclusions (without sections) `rightmark` is empty in even pages.

I would like some solution (maybe using `if` command) that changes *automatically* the above code by

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\small\textbf{\arabic{page}}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\small{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\small{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\space#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
```

(writes title chapter in even and odd pages).

Thank you

Comment: Why are you using `fancyhdr` with `memoir`? As with your other post some days ago: Don't post fragments only!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's have a look on what is the effect of this line:

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\space#1}{}}
```

Every time a `\chapter` appears, the current left- and rightmarks are overwritten: The leftmark by `\thechapter.\space#1` and the rightmark by an empty string. When after that a `\section` appears, only the rightmark is overwritten with the section title and number. One effect of this is that on even pages, that come after a `\chapter` but before any `\section`, the rightmark is empty.

If you want to change this behaviour, just let the `\chaptermark` also insert a rightmark:

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\space#1}{\thechapter.\space#1}}
```

Whenever there are sections present, nothing changes: The call of `\section` overwrites the rightmark set by `\chapter`. But when there is no `\section`, the header will use the chapter title and number as rightmarks.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\let\footruleskip\undefined
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\small\textbf{\arabic{page}}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\small{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\small{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\space#1}{\thechapter.\space#1}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Just}
\lipsum[2-4]

\section{some sections}
\lipsum[3-5]

\chapter{Second}
\lipsum[6-16]

\section{Section only now}
\lipsum[17-21]

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

You can achieve the same result without the use of `fancyhdr`. Just do the following replacements:

- `\pagestyle{fancy}` by `\pagestyle{myheadings}`
- `\fancyhead[LE}{...}` and so on by `\makeevenhead{myheadings}{<left>}{<center>}{<right>}` and `\makeoddhead` (similarily)
- `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}` by `\makeheadrule{myheadings}{\textwidth}{0.4pt}`

Full example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{myheadings}
\makeevenhead{myheadings}{\small\textbf{\arabic{page}}}{}{\small\rightmark}
\makeoddhead{myheadings}{\small\leftmark}{}{\small\textbf{\arabic{page}}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\space#1}{\thechapter.\space#1}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\space#1}}
\makeheadrule{myheadings}{\textwidth}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Just}
\lipsum[2-4]

\section{some sections}
\lipsum[3-5]

\chapter{Second}
\lipsum[6-16]

\section{Section only now}
\lipsum[17-21]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very good but you don't need `fancyhdr` as `memoir` has a more flexible method built in.

Comment: @Tiuri: The answer is that I was looking for. However, I will not mark it yet as accepted because I want @PeterWilson and @ChristianHupfer explain how to get the same result without using `fancyhdr`.

Comment: @Dog_69: See my update.